# Como consurmir API RestFull externa com o WebClient?

Tags: java, webclient

Gente, todos bem?
Estou querendo aprender a consumir um serviço externo com o WebClient, que no caso é este aqui
"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"

As classes que eu tenho são essa

```
    @Service
    @Slf4j
    public class JSONClient {
    
    
        static WebClient webClient;
    
    
        public JSONClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
            webClient = builder.baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/").build();
    
        }
    
        public static Mono<JSONModel> findACharacterById(String id) {
            log.info("Buscando personagem com o id [{}]", id);
            return webClient
                    .get()
                    .uri("/posts/" + id)
                    .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .retrieve()
                    .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError,
                            error -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException("verifique os parâmetros informados")))
                    .bodyToMono(JSONModel.class);
        }
    
      public static Mono<JSONModel> create(JSONModel jsonModel) {
         return webClient
                  .post()
                  .uri("/posts")
                  .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                  .body(jsonModel, JSONModel.class)
                  .retrieve()
                  .bodyToMono(JSONModel.class);
      }
    }



   @RestController
@RequestMapping("/web")
public class JSONController{

    JSONClient jsonClient;


    @GetMapping("/posts/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Mono<JSONModel> getCharacterById(@PathVariable String id) {
        return JSONClient.findACharacterById(id);

    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    //using Mono for single employee
    public Mono<JSONModel> create(@RequestBody JSONModel e) {
        return JSONClient.create(e);
    }

}


@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Data
    public class JSONModel {
    
        public String id;
        public String title;
        public String body;
        public String userId;
    
    }
```

O "get" funciona legal, mas eu estou tendo problema com o "post"
restorna esse erro no postman
body:

```
{  
    "title": "foo",
    "body": "bar",
    "userId": "1"
}
```

erro no postman

```
{
"timestamp": "2022-05-11T18:56:37.589+00:00",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"path": "/posts"
```

}

Se alguém puder me ajudar e também me mostrar alguma doc do webclient eu ficaria muito feliz, ainda estou meio perdido de entender melhor como utilizar o webclient para consumir APIs externas da minha aplicação.
Esse é o meu primeiro post, então desculpe se tiver algo errado

Answer (score 0):

Você não criou o caminho "/posts".

`@GetMapping("/posts/{id}")` -> cria o caminho **/web/posts/{id}** (método GET)

`@PostMapping` -> cria o caminho **/web** (método POST)

não existe nenhum path /posts no seu controller, por isso ocorre o erro 404

Você deve realizar o POST para /web apenas, ou adicionar o caminho /posts no seu método `create`

Comment: Vi sua resposta e vou testar em breve. Muito obrigado pelo help